# Traefik doesnt log to stdout

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, rancher, k3s, traefik-ingress

We’re running the default setup of k3s with traefik as ingress controller, and are having trouble getting traefik access logs working. I have set up a HelmChartConfig in `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/manifests/traefik-config.yaml` with the following content:
`apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1`

```
kind: HelmChartConfig
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  valuesContent: |-
    accessLog: {}
```

I would expect this to enable access logging to stdout, which should appear under `kubectl logs -n kube-system pod/traefik-<id>`, but that doesn’t show anything useful. Any hints?

Comment: Ok, what is `{}`? Actually you have not configured logging in any way, shape or form. Read the https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/blob/master/traefik/values.yaml